# Jaccard similarity calculation in recommenderlab package of R

Tags: r, similarity, collaborative-filtering

What is the role of the parameter 'alpha' in the recommenderlab R package's use of Jaccard method in the recommender model for boolean user-preferences matrix? ie

```
method="Jaccard",param=list(...,alpha=0.5)
```

I saw the code for IBCF and they used a dissimilarity function. But the function is not defined in the official CRAN PDF for the recommenderlab package. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

It is a function defined in recommenderlab. Try:

```
library("recommenderlab")
? dissimilarity
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

'''

"jaccard":
the number of items which occur in both elements divided by the total number of items in the elements (Sneath, 1957). This measure is often also called: binary, asymmetric binary, etc.

'''

So essentially, Jaccard = #(0 | 0) + #(1 | 1) similarities/ total.

Total is #(0 | 0) + #(1 | 1) + #(1 | 0) + #(0 | 1) ...ie, total number of rows. By # I mean number of matches, like COUNT in SQL. And my pipes, | , are meant as separators between two columns.

I had to first do ? dissimilarity, as recommended here by the documentation's author, Michael Hahsler (shout out!), and then go to dissimilarity {arules} documentation, which briefly describes the dissimilarity computations used in recommenderlab (cosine, pearson, and jaccard), as well as others.

Re: alpha... looks like it is used to help adjust bias related to highly popular items: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104811/what-does-the-parameter-alpha-do-in-the-jaccard-method-for-binaryratingsmatri